# Does Unbound always need to be in a `FreshM` monad?

Tags: haskell, scope, lambda-calculus

I'm working on a project based on [some existing code](https://github.com/adamgundry/type-inference/tree/master/src/PatternUnify) that uses the [unbound](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unbound) library.

The code uses `unsafeUnbind` a bunch, which is causing me problems.

I've tried using `freshen`, but I get the following error:

```
error "fresh encountered bound name! 
Please report this as a bug."
```

I'm wondering:

- Is the library intended to be used entirely within a `FreshM` monad? Or are their ways to do things like lambda application without being in `Fresh`?
- What kinds of values can I give to `freshen`, in order to avoid the errors they list?
- If I end up using `unsafeUnbind`, under what conditions is it safe to use?

Answer (score 6):

> Is the library intended to be used entirely within a `Fresh`M monad? Or are their ways to do things like lambda application without being in `Fresh`?

In most situations you will want to operate within a `Fresh` or an `LFresh` monad.

> What kinds of values can I give to `freshen`, in order to avoid the errors they list?

So I think the reason you're getting the error is because you're passing a *term* to `freshen` rather than a *pattern*.   In Unbound, patterns are like a generalization of names: a single `Name E` is a pattern consisting of a single variable which stands for `E`s, but also `(p1, p2)` or `[p]` are patterns comprised of a pair of patterns `p1` and `p2` or a list of patterns `p`, respectively.  This lets you define terms that bind two variables at the same time, for example.  Other more exotic type constructors include `Embed t` and `Rebind p1 p2` former makes a pattern that embeds a term inside of a pattern, while the latter is similar to `(p1,p2)` except that the names within `p1` scope over `p2` (for example if `p2` has `Embed`ed terms in it, `p1` will be scope over those terms).  This is really powerful because it lets you define things like Scheme's `let*` form, or *telescopes* like in dependently typed languages.  (See the paper for details).

Now finally the type constructor`Bind p t` is what brings a term and a type together: A term `Bind p t` means that the names in `p` are bound in `Bind p t` and scope over `t`.  So an (untyped) lambda term might be constructed with `data Expr = Lam (Bind Var Expr) | App Expr Expr | V Var` where `type Var = Name Expr`.

So back to `freshen`.  You should only call `freshen` on *patterns* so calling it on something of type `Bind p t` is incorrect (and I suspect the source of the error message you're seeing) - you should call it on just the `p` and then apply the resulting permutation to the term `t` to apply the renaming that `freshen` constructs.

> If I end up using `unsafeUnbind, under what conditions is it safe to use?

The place where I've used it is if I need to temporarily sneak under a binder and do some operation that I know for sure does not do anything to the names.  An example might be collecting some source position annotations from a term, or replacing some global constant by a closed term.  Also if you can guarantee that the term you're working with already has  been renamed so any names that you `unsafeUnbind` are going to be unique already.

Hope this helps.

PS: I maintain [unbound-generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unbound-generics) which is a clone of Unbound, but using GHC.Generics instead of RepLib.